# Are there many different power series representation for a given function?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

So I have to find the power series representation for $f(x) = \ln (3-x)$.

I attempted the following:

> $$\ln(3-x) =  \int {- \frac{1}{3-x} dx}$$ $$ = - \int {
>  \frac{1}{1-(x-2)} dx}$$ $$ = - \int {\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(x-2)^n} dx}$$ $$
>  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\int(x-2)^ndx}$$ $$ = \bigg(-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x-2)^{n+1}}{n+1}\bigg)+K $$

Then if we let $x=2$, then we obtain that $K=0$.
Hence the power series representation for $f(x)$ is $-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x-2)^{n+1}}{n+1}$, where $|x-2|<1$.

However the answer from my lecturer is given as:
$$\ln(3)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n\cdot3^n}}$$

Am I doing a mistake? Or are there many different power series representation for a given function? Any clarification would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It depends where you want to center your power series. Setting a given center, the power series representation is unique (and it exists for an holomorphic function).

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti thanks for your explanation! that makes perfect sense. however, the question does not really specify the center of the power series representation. does that mean that my answer is actually correct as well?

Comment: In a word, yes :) Ps. How do you justify the exachange of infinite summation and integral?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti is that because we are allowed to do term-by-term integration?

Comment: " the question does not really specify the center of the power series representation. does that mean that my answer is actually correct as well?" In a word, no because when the center is not specified one is supposed to understand the center is zero. (Additionnally, in some curricula the only admissible center is zero.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Your route is OK, but you should rather **start with**
$$
\ln(3-x) =  -\int_0^x { \frac{1}{3-t} dt}+\ln 3
$$ then follow the **same path** to obtain the right answer.

Comment: Thanks! I followed this and ended up in the same form. however, say in an exam i wrote like the above, would it be correct though?

Answer (score 1):

Both series are correct.  The one from the lecture is the series expansion around $x=0$, while the one derived in the posted question is the series expansion around $x=2$.  And one could choose other arbitrary points around which to expand the function.

Using a straightforward approach we see that for $f(x)=\log(3-x)$, we have for $n>0$

$$f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!(x-3)^{-n} \tag 1$$

We will use this in Approach 2 of the expansions around both $x=0$ and $x=3$ in that which follows.

---

**EXPANSION AROUND $x=0$**

**Approach 1:**
Using the approach outlined in the posted question, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\log(3-x)&=-\int_2^x \frac{1}{3-t}dt\\\\
&=-\int_2^x\frac{1}{1-(t-2)}dt\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^x (t-2)^n\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2)^n}{n}
\end{align}$$

which converges for $-1\le x<3$ and diverges otherwise.

---

**Approach 2:**
From $(1)$, we can see that $f^{(n)}(2)=(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!(-1)^{-n}=-(n-1)!$

Therefore, we can write the series representation as

$$\log(3-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2)^n}{n}$$

which converges for $-1\le x<3$ and diverges otherwise as expected!

---

**EXPANSION AROUND $x=3$**

**Approach 1:**
Using the approach outlined in the posted question, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\log(3-x)&=\log 3-\int_0^x \frac{1}{3-t}dt\\\\
&=\log 3-\frac13\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-(t/3)}dt\\\\
&=\log 3-\frac13\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^x (t/3)^n\\\\
&=\log 3-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n3^n}
\end{align}$$

which converges for $-3\le x<3$ and diverges otherwise.

---

**Approach 2:**
From $(1)$, we can also see that $f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!(-3)^{-n}=-\frac{(n-1)!}{3^n}$.

Therefore, we can write the series representation as

$$f(x)=\log 3-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n3^n}$$

which converges for $-3\le x<3$ and diverges otherwise as expected!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really just want to give you the best answer I can.